# Eigenvalues of random graphs

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, matrices, eigenvalues, random-graphs

At time $t=0$, let $G_n(V,E)$ be a graph with $n$ vertices and $m < n$ edges. Then there exists a unique symmetric adjacency matrix $A_n$ associated with $G_n(V,E)$, defined as follows: $a_{ij} = 1$ if there exists an edge between the vertex $i$ and vertex $j$, zero otherwise.

The spectrum, i.e., the set of eigenvalues of $A_n$ is not empty.

Then we consider at time $t=1$ a new vertex is added to the graph $G_n$ with probability $p$, $m<n+1$ edges connect the new vertex to the previous ones.

So the new adjacency matrix $A_{n+1}$ associated with the new graph $G_{n+1}$ has a new symmetric column/row where at least one entry is $1$ and in case all are ones.

Let us consider the sequence of matrices $G_n$ as $n$ tends to infinity. Can we say something on the associated sequence of eigenvalues?

Is there any reference on the subject?

Comment: You start with fixed $n$ and then want $n\to\infty$. It is strange. Am I correct to guess that actually you want $n$ fixed and then to make a sequence $G_{n+t}$ for $t=1,2,\ldots$ and ask about $t\to\infty$?

Comment: yes your guess is correct in fact you start with a graph of n vertex at $t=0$ at $t=1$ you add a new vertex so the graph $G_n$ becomes $G_{n+1}$ and so on so my question is on the eigenvalues of the associated adjacency matrix related to the sequence $G_n,G_{n+1},G_{n+2},..$

Answer (score 4):

The eigenvalues of $A_k$ *interlace* the eigenvalues of $A_{k+t}$, see e.g. Corollary 2.2 of a classical [“Interlacing eigenvalues and graphs”](http://members.upc.nl/w.haemers/interlacing.pdf) by W.Haemers, which however mostly deals with various “regular” cases.

There are lots of references on interlacing and graphs to check for what you might need.
[This one](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X04003644) lists some.

---

Incidentally, interlacing plays important role in the recent [proof](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~hhuan30/papers/sensitivity_1.pdf) of  [Sensitivity Conjecture](https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=4229#comment-1813084) by Huang.

Comment: thanks this was precisely what I was asking.

Comment: @pjicome Given your answer to my comment above, interlacing will not be of much use I fear.  It is a very weak property for the eigenvalues of very large graph to be interlaced by those of a small subgraph.  The main useful observation is that the largest eigenvalue increases and the smallest decreases.

Comment: @dpasechick I need a general property because I would like to study not a general random graph but I am interested in a particular graph  a generalization of the the so called apollonian network https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378437105004450  in this case very time we add a new vertex the corresponding matrices become the previous one plus an extra column where we have a fixed number of 1s.

Comment: incidentally, interlacing plays important role in the recent http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~hhuan30/papers/sensitivity_1.pdf

Comment: @BrendanMcKay   there an insanely clever trick replaces some entries 1 in the adjacency matrix on n-dimensional hypercube with -1s, to obtain a matrix proportional to an involuntary one. So the eigenvalues are all the same in absolute value, and one can say more about eigenvalues of principal submatrices.